# Mounting truecrypt volume under PHP

Tags: php, exec

I would like to mount a trucrypt volume using PHP, but I'm getting the following return value from the exec command:    `Enter keyfile [none]:`

This is how i tried:
First try:

```
truecrypt -p password --fs-options=users,uid=$(id -u mysql),gid=$(id -g mysql),fmask=0113,dmask=0002 --mount /media/vulturus_data/test2 /media/true/
```

Second try:

```
truecrypt --fs-options=users,uid=$(id -u mysql),gid=$(id -g mysql),fmask=0113,dmask=0002 --mount /media/vulturus_data/test2 /media/true/ << EOF password EOF
```

If I'm executing in command line this command, then it is working without any problem.

I also included the following line  `%www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/truecrypt`
 in to `/etc/sudoers`

**UPDATED**

---

This is my environmental variables:

```
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-robu
SSH_AGENT_PID=13131
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=c1bdff7bae779799d48380cc4dede420-1328690954.481942-1775992192
WINDOWID=69206021
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-MHRREA
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
USER=robu
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:hl=44;37:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-MHRREA/ssh
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.default.path
S    ESSION_MANAGER=local/vulturus:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/13094,unix/vulturus:/tmp/.ICE-unix/13094
USERNAME=robu
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/etc/xdg
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PWD=/home/robu
GDM_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT=us
LANG=en_US.utf8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=13076
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.mandatory.path
GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
GDMSESSION=gnome
SPEECHD_PORT=7560
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/robu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=robu
X    DG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-X2vS4Wtxb9,guid=be42629003d6f13a98884ed54f32370a
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DISPLAY=:0.0
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-robu-TBzbLF/database
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the --non-interactive option:

```
$mount = 'sudo truecrypt  -p '.$pass['truecrypt_pass']." --slot=".(20+$data->id);
        if($data->is_ntfs == 0)
            $mount .= ' --filesystem=ntfs-3g ';

        if($data->is_ntfs == 1)
            $mount .= ' --fs-options="users,uid=$(id -u mysql),gid=$(id -g mysql),fmask=0027,dmask=0027"';

        if($data->key_file)
            $mount .= " -k ".$data->key_file;
        $mount .= ' --mount '.$data->volume_location.' '.$data->mount_point." --non-interactive " ;

        shell_exec($mount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the key file is found as part of your environment variables, or a path in there somewhere.  As you have suspected, PHP is running as a different user.

Assuming there is no permissions issue, I would look to seeing what is defined in your environment, and setting it explicitly when you execute TrueCrypt.

Comment: I also tried to use shell_exec: echo shell_exec("/var/www/truecrypt/components/com_truecrypt/assets/bash.sh"); with the same result

Comment: Hi, I just added environment variables